# Bulk move via CMD Regex

Tags: windows-10, command-line, regex, file-transfer

I have about 15k files in a flat folder. All are named something like `blah blah - whatever.png`. Basically, I'd like to move them all into folders named `blah blah`. I don't want to rename any of them, just bump them into their respective folders. I imagine I need to do this with some kind of regex, but I can't seem to workout how to apply regex in this context.

Comment: I just tried 
    for %A IN (*.docx) DO move "%A" "^[^-]*[^ -]/%A"
And it didn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` command does not support regular expressions.

Assuming all files contain a `-` character, you could probably use this code in a batch file:

```sh
for /f "delims=- tokens=1* usebackq" %%a in (`dir /b *.png`) do (
    if not exist "%%a" mkdir "%%a"
    move "%%a-%%b" "%%a"
)
```

`delims=-` will split the filenames on `-`, giving you the directory name which will be created if it doesn't exist yet. Next, the original filename, `%%a-%%b`, will be moved to that directory.

Comment: I tried that and the output was to create directories named `blah blah - ` (including the hyphen), and it didn't move anything (presumably because the naming convention of the directory didn't align). I've tried munging through it a bit, but haven't been able to make that work _fully_.

Comment: @LincM That is strange. By definition the `-` shouldn't be part of `%%a`, because the filename is split on it. Could it be that it's not really a hyphen but another utf dash symbol?

Comment: I don't believe it's another UTF. What is might do is use this as a batch instead of as a command and see if it works differently.

Comment: @LincM, yes this code was meant as a batch. I'll add that to my answer

Comment: Ah, okay well that works. I was hoping to be able to understand the structure of how one may do this directly  through commandline instead of running a batch, but this achieves what I'm after, thanks!